# Is there any geometry behind the Basel problem?

Tags: sequences-and-series, geometry, algebraic-geometry, riemann-zeta, big-list

I could find many beautiful and rigorous proofs for Euler's solution to the Basel problem here   [Different methods to compute $\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^2}$ (Basel problem)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/8337/different-methods-to-compute-sum-limits-k-1-infty-frac1k2-basel-pro)

[image: Basel problem solution]

But I am curious to know whether there are proofs by using geometry.

If anyone has proofs by geometry, please do share it with us.

Comment: [Here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/112062/geometric-physical-probabilistic-interpretations-of-riemann-zetan1) is an MO thread you may find interesting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Funny you should ask this today. A great video [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d-o3eB9sfls) by the YouTuber 3Blue1Brown was just posted today. (Aside: I recommend all his videos.)

The proof is based on the result mentioned by "3 revs" in the MO thread mentioned by user296602 above.

Comment: Don't be sorry. It's great stuff. Have a nice day.

Comment: "3 revs" is not a user, it means "3 revisions" (of a community wiki post). A better identifier is obtained by clicking "share", which gives you a direct link to that answer: https://mathoverflow.net/a/178206/4678.

Comment: @user357980: Wonderful reference. (+1)